# How to add user control into groupbox

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, user-controls

I have c# winform application and one WPF user control. How i can add groupbox(which is in winform) controls my wpf usercontrol?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're trying to add a WPF control to a WinForms app, right?  Not simply trying to find the GroupBox control's equivalent in WPF? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) control to the groupbox and add WPF usercontrol in the ElementHost.

See [here](http://www.programmerfish.com/how-to-add-wpf-controls-in-simple-windows-forms/) and [here](http://www.nayyeri.net/host-wpf-controls-in-windows-forms) for good articles.